# Force some pages over HTTPS and others to HTTP... is it possible?

Tags: iis, redirect, ssl, url-rewriting

I'm really stuck on this one...

Basically, I'm trying to make 2 pages always over SSL using the URLRewrite add-on for IIS.  But I also need to force all other pages to HTTP (sigh - don't ask).

But if I force other pages over HTTP, then when you view the SSL page you'll get the security warning.  I tried to solve this by checking if the HTTP_REFERER is the SSL page then let it be sent over SSL for that page only.  This doesn't work because if someone clicks a link on the SSL page then it will stay over SSL.

Is this even possible?...

This is as far as I got so far:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS Login" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.+)login.aspx" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS Payments" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.+)payments.aspx" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Others Force HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match negate="true" url="((.+)login.aspx|(.+)payments.aspx)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" negate="true" pattern="(.+)login.aspx" />
                <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" negate="true" pattern="(.+)payments.aspx" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

UPDATE: Found this article: [Rewrite http to https on some pages only using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357455/rewrite-http-to-https-on-some-pages-only-using-htaccess/8191154#8191154). No answer since March 2010...!

Comment: "No answer since March 2010...!" ==> Why are you using IIS? I could have answered with Apache in less than a blink of an eye. Better, faster, safer, and free (in *every* way). Sorry I couldn't help that.

Comment: Thanks Oliver.  Yeah, it ended up being easier than I thought.  :P

As far as I know, this URLRewrite add-on can do the same as htaccess.  But yes, I prefer htaccess as well (been around longer and more resources, etc).  I believe you can even use htaccess with IIS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is:

1. Force HTTPS for the page(s) that required it.
2. Force all other pages to HTTP EXCEPT for the page(s) in point#1 and the "/styles" and "/images" folders that are referenced on these pages.

Since the pages use relative paths, they automatically use the styles/images over HTTP/HTTPS respectively.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS Login" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)/login.aspx" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Others Force HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(((.*)/login.aspx)|((.*)/styles(.*))|((.*)/images(.*)))" negate="true" />
            <conditions>  
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```