# Enable ASP.NET to use SSL for few pages, others should work as HTTP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, url-rewriting, web-config

In my web application few of my pages requires SSL (2 or 3) but everything else should work as HTTP.

So I tried page redirection in prerender which doesnt seems to be a good solution. Mainly because when redirecting from those pages the resultant pages keeps as HTTPS. So how can we make this possible with URL rewriting or some other nice way

Comment: Check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8220692](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8220692)

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to make only two urls available in HTTPS: `/abc` and `/xyz`, and all others should be under HTTP. You need to use this rule:

```
<rule name="abc and xyz redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(abc|xyz)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
<rule name="other than abc or xyz redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(abc|xyz)$" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```